# Accidental loss of all code - recovery help please

Tags: git, data-recovery

I've recently been using a local git directory and spent 2 months without committing anything and working locally in the directory.

Today I launched the GIT GUI and accidentally clicked "abort merge" and now i've lost the past 2 months of work in the directory - it's reverted to the last state of the GIT.

Is there any way I can get this back?

Comment: This doesn't help, but it's the kind of mistake you'll only make once in your career. You'll be the version control and backup *king* from now on.

Comment: I think this probably belongs on superuser, you're really asking about data recovering (since as you say, you weren't really using Git).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't commit, I don't think `git` will know about your code. This is bad practice. You should always make small commits as you go along. What's the point in using a version control system if you don't commit any code for 2 whole months?

Did you do a `git stash` at any time during these months? It's possible then that the tree at that point in time will be there in your repository. Apart from that, I think you've lost your work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. No, this was the first time i've ever used GIT and eventually just reverted to working purely locally in the same directory just without using any GIT functionality.

Do you think i'd be able to recover it using a hard drive recovery program or something?

Comment: No harm trying but don't get your hopes up.

Comment: Thanks :) i've managed to piece together an up to date copy based on a backup i'd randomly chosen to upload to BOX completely by chance two days ago, decompiling an Android APK which contained code i'd uploaded 2 hours ago and a partial copy of some of the code on a webserver.
Suffice to say i got off lightly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to recover your code using file recovery tools (like when your hard drive is crashed or when you delete accidentaly file from the explorer). But if you tell to the version control manager that you want to cancel your local changes, it listen to you :(

Comment: cheers! any suggested hard drive recovery programs?

Comment: I don't know much about such tools... may be here : http://lifehacker.com/5237503/five-best-free-data-recovery-tools